# Is updating a non-indexed column quicker if the where clause is indexed in SQL?

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-update, where-clause

Basically I'm trying to update a table in SQL and I was wondering whether I could increase the speed if I add indices to the columns in my `where` clause.

For example:

```
Update mytable 
Set code1 = 1   
Where Account > 115 and Account < 350
```

If I add an index to the column `Account`, would it increase or decrease my speed?

Comment: It depends on the size of the table. If it is below the threshold where a full table scan is faster than the detour via an index or any other circumstance, that has that result, then no, it won't speed it up. Otherwise yes, if the optimizer picks the index up, that is. Why don't you just try it?

Comment: Indexing isn't as easy as it sounds.  How many indexes are there on the table already?  How many rows?  Is account evenly distributed or not?  But as indicated above, if the optimizer uses the index, it will be faster.

Comment: Check the execution plan

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
Update mytable
    Set code1 = 1   
    Where Account > 115 and Account < 350;
```

Under most circumstances, an index on `mytable(Account)` will speed up performance of this query.  The index will allow the the database engine to quickly find the rows that match the query, and then to update only those rows.

When will this not work?  The use of an index depends on the selectivity of the index (or more precisely, the estimated selectivity during the optimization phase).  For instance, if all accounts are in that range, then an index does not help.  But in general, the index will help.

Comment: Gordon thanks for the comment. I did give it a try and I did notice a difference in speed.